# Character encoding issue in GHC

Tags: haskell, character-encoding

When I try and read a plaintext file from within my Haskell program I get:

[fromList *** Exception: /path/to/file/aaa.txt hGetContents: invalid argument (Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character)

I googled to find this problem is usually set right by setting LANG to en_US.UTF-8
That's already how my locale looks.

Not sure if this is an issue with GHC at all.

I am on Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure aaa.txt contains valid UTF-8? If it's binary data, you need to use [withBinaryFile](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3awithBinaryFile) or similar. If it is text in another encoding, you should use [hSetEncoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3ahSetEncoding).

For instance, if your text is in Latin-1 then you would say

```
hSetEncoding h latin1
```

where "h" is your file handle.  If you are reading from standard input then its

```
hSetEncoding stdin latin1
```

There is also a [mkTextEncoding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#v%3amkTextEncoding) function which you can use if you have read the encoding from metadata, or wish to customise the handling of invalid Unicode (although this only works on some systems).

The Unicode standards say that a Unicode parser should reject invalid strings with an error, rather than trying to fix them up.  This is a deliberate rejection of [Postel's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle), on the grounds of reducing security holes and inconsistent interpretations.

(You might want to consider using the [text](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) library if you'll be working with a lot of text and having to handle encoding issues; it's usually a lot faster than using Strings, since it uses an unboxed array rather than a linked list, although this means that Text values and operations on them are necessarily strict. It also lets you configure [how to respond to invalid Unicode](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/text/latest/doc/html/Data-Text-Encoding-Error.html#t%3aOnDecodeError) more portably and flexibly.)

Comment: These are plain text files from gutenberg. I just checked, the files say "Character set encoding: ISO Latin-1" What's the way to use hSetEncoding? I can't find an example.I tried putting the line hSetEncoding = "latin1" and it compiles but gives the same error

Comment: `hSetEncoding h latin1`, where `h` is your file handle. Have you read a Haskell tutorial? No offence, it's just that it makes things like using standard library functions easier :)

Comment: (You can see the list of TextEncoding values [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO.html#t:TextEncoding); equivalently, by clicking the TextEncoding link in hSetEncoding's type signature on the same page.)

Comment: and the default TextEncoding mode under linux will be from LANG so the file must be an utf8 encoded file and not a iso-8859 file.

Comment: @Jonke: Right, which is why you should use hSetEncoding if you know what the encoding is :)

Comment: @Paul Johnson: Are you sure the Unicode standards say that? I can certainly believe that they recommend it, but [U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) seems to exist for the purpose of replacing rejected sequences with it.